# Populate doubly linked list with Database and display

Tags: c#, sql, database, doubly-linked-list, sqldataadapter

I have been playing around with SQL and doubly linked lists in C# and I wanted to know if anyone knows of a way to display information from an SQL server file I created, which shows fake bank transactions by prompting the user for an account number and display it in a doubly linked list.

```
public class Transaction
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        //variables of the Book Table created
        int AccountNo;
        DateTime Date;
        string Description;
        string DebitCredit;
        Double Amount;
        public Transaction(int ACCNo, DateTime TimeDate, string description,                  string CreditDebit, double amount)
        //constructor
        {
            this.AccountNo = ACCNo;
            this.Date = TimeDate;
            this.Description = description;
            this.DebitCredit = CreditDebit;
            this.Amount = amount;
        }
        //My current print method
        public string PrintNodes(LinkedList<int> values)
        {
            if (values.Count != 0)
            {
                Output += "Here are your transaction details:";

                foreach (Transaction t in values)
                {
                    Output += "\r\n" + t;
                }
                Output += "\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                Output += "The Doubly Linked List is empty!";
            }
        }
    }
//my method for taking the information from database and pasting into DLL
    public void FillText(LinkedList<Transaction> values)
        {
            LinkedList<Transaction> Transactions = new LinkedList<Transaction>(); //create the generic linked list

            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"dbConnection1"].ConnectionString); //Connection string

            int AccountNo = Int32.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter account number", "Account Number")); //Prompt the user for account number


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Transactions where AccountNo = " + AccountNo, conn); //command to execute
            conn.Open();  //open the connection to the database           
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (reader.HasRows)//Check if the table has records
            {
                while (reader.Read()) //read all records with the given AccountNo
                {
                    Transaction Transaction001 = new Transaction(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetDateTime(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetDouble(4)); //New Transaction node
                    Transactions.AddFirst(Transaction001);// add the node to the Doubly Linked List (Transactions)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found");
            }

            txtOutput.Text = Transactions.PrintNodes();

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I want it to display along the lines of:

```
Transactions for account 12345678

Date              Description              Debit/Credit       Amount

01/01/2015        Hello eofcoef            C                  $1000.00
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. I want to be able to take information from an SQL database file, bring it into a Doubly Linked List and then print this information. I think I have managed to bring the information into the DLL properly but I cannot seem to work out the Print method for the DLL. How do I properly print the DLL data so I can show the information taken from the SQL file?

Comment: Can you then edit your question to add a sample of the data and show it should be displayed, and reduce the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at splitting responsibilities in the code. You have the object Transaction defined, that is used to descibe a transaction. However, in it you have now added a list of other transactions and methods for displaying transactions in this list. Move that to another class, as you want a transaction to be uniform and atomic, meaning that it is "just" a description of the transaction.

Then you would have a different type of object designed to work with and handle groups of transactions. You could change the FillText method to return a Transaction, the return with this-keyword, the object you instantiated (like a builder pattern). That way you may init the connections outside and then break out the PrintNodes as that does not belong in Transaction-object.

As for printing, you are printing the object reference itself...

```
 foreach (Transaction t in values)
            {
                Output += "\r\n" + t;
            }
            Output += "\r\n";
```

You need to deref the properties you want, like so:

```
 foreach (Transaction t in values)
            {
                //Formatting code needed for tabbed appearance
                Output += "\r\n" + t.Description + "\t" + t.DebitCard;     
                //etc...


            }
            Output += "\r\n";
```

You could also override ToString() for in the class Transaction, to just refer to it as it's name (given you supply a custom string returned from this overriden method), like:

```
public override string ToString(){ //Return a formatted string here }
```